# validation ignores one of the conditions - yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to validate before save and see if the store_id/period exists. But it's strange, it's validating for the entire store_idS, but it's suppose to see only one of the id.

It's ignoring that store_id, and checks for the entire data. So when there are dates found, it returns everything related to that date, ignoring the store_id. I'm not looking for everything, I just want the store.

in model:

```
public function pExists($attribute, $params)
    {
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('store_id',$this->store_id); //<--it's ignoring this... 

        $criteria->addBetweenCondition('date_from', $this->date_from, $this->date_to);
        $criteria->addBetweenCondition('date_to', $this->date_from, $this->date_to, 'OR');

        $model = $this->exists($criteria);
        if (!empty($model)) {
            $this->addError($attribute, "Promotional Fee already exists in period.");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('date_from', $this->date_from, $this->date_to);
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('date_to', $this->date_from, $this->date_to, 'OR');
$criteria->compare('store_id',$this->store_id);
```

Comment: the position of OR is different in your case. (store_id = :store_id and date between ...) OR (date between....)